# In Python 3.2, is "lambda" considered a "keyword," an "operator" or both?

Tags: python, lambda, language-lawyer

In Python 3.2, according to this: http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/expressions.html#summary

`lambda` is the operator with the lowest precedence in Python.

And according to this: http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords

`lambda` is a Python language keyword.

HOWEVER, according to this: http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/lexical_analysis.html#other-tokens

Operators and keywords are distinct entities.

I'm trying to systematically explain Python 3.2 to someone and I don't want to confuse them.  I, myself, am confused, though, on the exact definitions of operators and keywords.

*My best guess is that the term "operator" means something slightly different when used in the context of the Python parser versus the Python lexer.*

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's sensible to call `lambda` a keyword rather than an operator.

Comment: @alberge What's your reasoning?

Comment: I clearly engaged the fingers before the brain. Several python keywords *are* operators. They appear to be overlapping sets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lambda` clearly is a keyword; it's a special word recognised by the parser, which would otherwise fall within the definition of an `identifier`.

`lambda` is not *semantically* an operator. An operator is just a function, but invoked with a different syntax. We can imagine replacing the `+` operator with an `add` function; all our programs with addition would get more verbose and harder to read, but we could still write them. The `lambda` language construct on the other hand could not be replaced with a function; `lambda x: x+1` is not just calculating a result from the values `x` and `x+1`, because in this context they are not values at all (`x` is the name of the parameter to the function being defined, and `x+1` is the code of the lambda body).

In the same page you linked to we have: http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/lexical_analysis.html#operators

> The following tokens are operators:
>
> ```
> +       -       *       **      /       //      %
> <<      >>      &       |       ^       ~
> <       >       <=      >=      ==      !=
> ```

That's the entire contents of the subsection on operators. From this I take it to mean that in the context of defining the tokens of the language "operators" are symbolic operators, whereas the section on *keywords* is explicitly spelling out that "these things which would otherwise be identifiers are keywords". That's why I think the keyword operators like `not`, `is`, `in`, etc are not listed. But there certainly are things that are semantically operators that are keywords, whether or not the parser considers them separate classes.

I'm not sure why http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/expressions.html#summary describes `lambda` as an operator; I certainly wouldn't. Strictly speaking it doesn't explicitly say "`lambda` is the operator with the lowest precedence", it just lists `lambda` in a table whose column heading is "Operator". Perhaps it was just a convenience; describing `lambda` as a thing with low precedence is a good way of clarifying how Python will parse `lambda x: x + 1` (it could theoretically be either `(lambda x: x) + 1` or `lambda x: (x + 1)`).

Comment: Just because we can’t replace the `lambda` construct with a different function, it does not make `lambda` not a function. It is a somewhat unary function (if you take the parameter matcher out) that takes an expression and returns a function. It is clearly an operator as it takes an expression and returns an expression (of type function).

Comment: @poke No it's not a function, precisely because it needs an expression. You don't pass expressions to functions, you pass values. If you try to view `lambda` you don't "pass" it a value, you pass it an expression (which cannot be "passed" to any other kind of function). Otherwise it would be valid to bind the expression to a name and pass the name instead: `x = fire_ze_missiles(); f = lambda: x` is **very** different from `f = lambda: fire_ze_missiles()`, while `x = fire_ze_missiles(); y = x + 1` is equivalent to `y = fire_ze_missiles() + 1`.

Comment: I agree: `lambda` does not "smell like" an operator.  And as you note precedence tables are not just for operators: they're really a way for humans to deal with binding-strengths when looking at what would otherwise be an ambiguous parse.  We're merely used to seeing such ambiguity when dealing with expressions-with-operators.

Answer (score 4):

> Operators and keywords are distinct entities.

No they're not. `is`, `in`, `and`, `or`, `not`, and I'm sure a few more are both.

Comment: Why doesn't this list those as operators?  It implies (informally) that it lists all tokens that are operators.  Those are clearly tokens, yet aren't in the list:  http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/lexical_analysis.html#operators

Comment: Simply because they are already in the list of reserved keywords.

Answer (score 2):

That doesn't say they're mutually exclusive, just that:

> "the following categories of tokens exist: identifiers, keywords,
>   literals, operators, and delimiters"

I'm in the categories person and American.  Granted, it may mean to imply that they're mutually exclusive, in which case the docs are inconsistent.

Comment: That sentence bothers me, because of that and because it didn't give an umbrella term for INDENT, DEINDENT and NEWLINE.  When explaining the notion of a Python token, I do not know if I should combine those three into a single type, or leave them separately.  I guess that's irrelevant to this question, but I'm trying really hard to systematize the basics of Python.

Comment: Those three are all statement separators/markers.  INDENT AND DEINDENT are used to mark compound statements (and function and class bodies), while NEWLINE separates simple statements.

Comment: I've been studying the grammar; Do you know the official term for it and can you cite it?  The document I'm writing -- I want it to use only official jargon, if possible.

Comment: @WordsLikeJared, try the term "significant whitespace"